# Word to binary numbers program in C

Tags: c, binary, segmentation-fault, bit, coredump

I am trying to make program that converts word to binary numbers.
For Example:

Input:

> abcd

Output(Firstly the ascii code of a,b,c and d):

> (ASCII CODE of a,b,c and d)
>
> a: 97
>
> b: 98
>
> c: 99
>
> d: 100
>
> Than convert these to binary:
>
> 97: 1100001
>
> 98: 1100010
>
> 99: 1100011
>
> 100: 1100100
>
> And finally the output should be like this:
>
> 110000|11100010|1100011|1100100
>
> Or without the straight lines between them.

But i am getting an error :

Input:

> a

Output:

> Segmentation failed(core dumped)

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAXINPUTCHAR 100
#define MAXBINARYNUMERAL 32

int thestr[MAXINPUTCHAR];
int theastr[MAXINPUTCHAR];
int thebstr[MAXINPUTCHAR][MAXBINARYNUMERAL];
//function declerations...
void mydtob(int,int*);//Decimal to binary converter
void mystreverse(int*);//Reverse the string
void mycopy(int*,int*);//Copy array into array
void mystoa(int*,int*);//Char array to ascii codes of the chars array
void mydtobhelper(int*,int [MAXINPUTCHAR][MAXBINARYNUMERAL]);//The function that loops through and calls mydtob
void mygetline(int*);
void printArray(int [MAXINPUTCHAR][MAXBINARYNUMERAL]);//Print 2D array
void mymdcp(int target[MAXINPUTCHAR][MAXBINARYNUMERAL],int* from,int targetIndex);//Copy array to 2D array

int main(void) {
    mygetline(thestr);
    mystoa(thestr,theastr);
    mydtobhelper(theastr,thebstr);
    printArray(thebstr);
    return 0;
}

void mydtobhelper(int* decimal,int target[MAXINPUTCHAR][MAXBINARYNUMERAL]){
    int singlenumbinary[MAXBINARYNUMERAL];
    for(int i=0;decimal[i];i++){
        mydtob(decimal[i],singlenumbinary);
        mymdcp(target,singlenumbinary,0);
        target[i+1][0]='\0';
    }
}

void mydtob(int decimal,int* target){
    int base=2;
    int quotient=decimal;
    int remainder=0;
    int i=0;
    while(quotient!=0){
        remainder=quotient%base;
        quotient=quotient/base;
        target[i]=remainder+'0';
        target[i+1]='\0';
        i++;
    }
    mystreverse(target);
}

void printArray(int arraytoprint[MAXINPUTCHAR][MAXBINARYNUMERAL]){
    char convertedarr[MAXINPUTCHAR][MAXBINARYNUMERAL];
    for(int i=0;i<MAXINPUTCHAR;i++) {
        for(int k=0;i<MAXBINARYNUMERAL;k++){
            convertedarr[i][k]=arraytoprint[i][k];
        }
    }
    for(int i=0;convertedarr[i][0];i++){
        printf("%s",convertedarr[i]);   
    }   
}

void mystreverse(int* str){
    int copiedstr[MAXINPUTCHAR];
    int i=0;
    for(i=0;str[i];i++);
    i--;    
    mycopy(str,copiedstr);
    for (int k=i;k>=0;k--){
        str[k]=copiedstr[i-k];
    }
    str[i+1]='\0';
}

void mycopy(int* from,int* target){
    for(int i=0;from[i];i++){
        target[i]=from[i];
        target[i+1]='\0';
    }
}

void mystoa(int* str,int* target) {
  for (int i = 0; str[i];i++) {
    //printf("%d\n",i);
    if (str[i] >= 'a' && str[i] <= 'z' || str[i]==' ' || str[i]=='\t') {
      int n = str[i];
      target[i]=n;
      target[i+1]='\0';
    }
  }
}

void mygetline(int* target){
    int i=0;
    int c=0;
    while((c=getchar())!=EOF && c != '\n'){
        target[i]=c;
        target[i+1]='\0';
        i++;
    }
}

void mymdcp(int target[MAXINPUTCHAR][MAXBINARYNUMERAL], int* from, int targetIndex) {
    for (int j = 0; j < from[j]; j++) {
        target[targetIndex][j] = from[j];
    }
}
```

Comment: where are you getting the error? and one think i think you could achieve this with less code, by using bit manipulation to get the binary numbers and the ASCII you can use enums or char conversion to int

Comment: `mystoa() ` is a problem if `str` was something like `"ABC"` as target would be missing a value for `target[0]`... `target[2]` and it would not be null character terminated.  Unclear on function's  goal.

Comment: @Muhamed-- Please, please learn how to use a debugger. I used gdb to find the error causing your segfault in literally 30 seconds. You could have found this in less time than it took to post the question! You will notice that everyone here is constantly imploring people to use a debugger. That is because we use them all the time, and know how much time they can save. It would be well worth an afternoon to learn the rudiments of gdb or some other debugger of your choice! On a positive note, thank you for posting a complete file that compiles.

Comment: @DavidBowling I'm sorry.I'm new to C.And i didn't know which debugger can i use.I will try gdb.Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The segmentation fault is being caused by a faulty loop in the function `printArray()`:

```
for(int k=0;i<MAXBINARYNUMERAL;k++){
   convertedarr[i][k]=arraytoprint[i][k];
```

The `i` in the loop condition should be a `k`. When this is fixed, the program works:

```
λ> ./a.out 
z
1111010
λ> ./a.out 
a
1100001
λ> ./a.out 
f
1100110
```

## Edit

I think that code readability may have been an issue here. Consider the code as it was originally formatted:

```
void printArray(int arraytoprint[MAXINPUTCHAR][MAXBINARYNUMERAL]){
    char convertedarr[MAXINPUTCHAR][MAXBINARYNUMERAL];
    for(int i=0;i<MAXINPUTCHAR;i++) {
        for(int k=0;i<MAXBINARYNUMERAL;k++){
            convertedarr[i][k]=arraytoprint[i][k];
        }
    }
    for(int i=0;convertedarr[i][0];i++){
        printf("%s",convertedarr[i]);   
    }
    putchar('\n');
}
```

compared with this:

```
void printArray(int arraytoprint[MAXINPUTCHAR][MAXBINARYNUMERAL])
{
    char convertedarr[MAXINPUTCHAR][MAXBINARYNUMERAL];

    for (int i = 0;i < MAXINPUTCHAR; i++) {
        for (int k = 0;i < MAXBINARYNUMERAL; k++){
            convertedarr[i][k] = arraytoprint[i][k];
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0;convertedarr[i][0]; i++){
        printf("%s", convertedarr[i]);   
    }
    putchar('\n');
}
```

Both of these snippets contain the original error, but the second one makes it just a little easier to spot, since the symbols aren't quite as crammed together.

Comment: I just wonder,how did u find the bug that fast.I mean even though its debugger.Its not that easy to find it ?

Comment: @MuhamedCicak-- [Here](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~gilpin/tutorial/), [here](http://cs.baylor.edu/~donahoo/tools/gdb/tutorial.html), and [here](http://www.cs.umd.edu/~srhuang/teaching/cmsc212/gdb-tutorial-handout.pdf) are tutorials on using gdb.  This is not the place for a tutorial, but briefly, I compiled your code with debugging symbols and ran it in gdb. When it segfaulted, gdb told me what function that happened in. I didn't immediately see the problem, so I put in a `printf()` to show the values of `i` and `k`, and saw that `k` just kept growing. Aha!

Comment: @MuhamedCicak-- as a side note, it was a little difficult to read your code because you don't use many spaces or blank lines. That makes errors like the one that you had hard to spot (hence my use of the `printf()` statement). If you try to format your code for readability you are less likely to need a debugger to find such a simple typo. Still, learn how to use one. That time will pay off.

Comment: @MuhamedCicak-- added an edit to my answer about code readability.

Comment: I guess i should buy IDE like CLion.I was programming in CLion for free trial,and i had no issues with code readibility becuase you have an option to auto format code.But because it expiried (the free trial) i now program in Sublime Text.Do you know any free IDE,that has auto format code ?. Because i was searching for a while and i couldn't find.

Comment: I just use a text editor. Usually emacs, sometimes vim. Both do automatic indentation and syntax highlighting. I believe that Sublime also has these features.